# insert_iterator invalidation rules

Tags: c++, iterator, insert-iterator

What actions to an STL container can invalidate a C++ `std::insert_iterator` referencing that container? Is an `insert_iterator` valid iff its underlying iterator (protected member `iter`) is, subject to the usual [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6438086/985943)?

Related: [std::insert_iterator and iterator invalidation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9154408/985943) gives an example of an invalid `insert_iterator` but did not elucidate the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is an insert_iterator valid iff its underlying iterator (protected member iter) is,

You are correct, that's the reason that protected member is listed in the spec and the functions that work on the `insert_iterator` (specifically, `operator=`, since the rest is no-ops) are defined in terms of functions that access `iter`

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer depends on what specifically you are asking about.

(To get this out of the way, I'd like to immediately note that your "Related" link is completely unrelated. The problem with the code at that link has absolutely nothing to do with `insert_iterator` invalidation. The author of that question misinterpreted the issue and ended up trying to solve a non-existent problem, while the real problem persisted. I provided an extra answer to that question as well.)

If you create an `insert_iterator ins` from a valid iterator `container::iterator it` and then independently do something to the container that would invalidate `it`, then `ins` will also get invalidated. This is something that is natural to expect. The `ins` has no way to know that something happened to the container if you do it independently.

However, at the same time `insert_iterator` has self-repairing properties when it is used for insertion. For example, if you use `insert_iterator ins` to insert data into a `vector`, `ins` remains valid even if vector goes through reallocation. I.e. even though vector reallocation is a massive iterator-invalidating event, it does not damage `ins` (assuming, of course, that the reallocation was triggered by an insertion performed through `ins`).

This follows from the standard insertion algorithm

```
it = container->insert(it, value);
++it;
```

where `it` is the underlying insertion point iterator stored inside `insert_iterator`. Front-inserting and back-inserting iterators also have the same "self-healing" properties. A potentially invalid internal iterator gets immediately re-validated.

To illustrate the difference, consider this simple example

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin() + 5;

for (unsigned n = 20; n > 0; --n)
  v.insert(it, rand());
```

This code is generally invalid, since it is very likely that the container will reallocate during insertion cycle, thus invalidating `it` and rendering all further insertions invalid.

At the same time this code

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin() + 5;
std::insert_iterator<std::vector<int> > it_ins(v, it);

for (unsigned n = 20; n > 0; --n)
  *it_ins++ = rand();
```

is guaranteed to work fine, regardless of whether the vector reallocates or not.

Comment: Your first point is what I meant by 'subject to the usual invalidation rules.' Your second point is illuminating: an `insert_iterator` may invalidate its _own_ internal iterator, via the call to `insert()`, only to revalidate it by exploiting the fact that `insert()` returns a valid iterator. However, at every sequence point in the standard insertion algorithm you describe, I believe that the iterators are both valid or invalid; thus I believe the if-and-only-if (and accepted answer) still holds.

Comment: @nknight: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by *"at every sequence point in the standard insertion algorithm you describe, I believe that the iterators are both valid or invalid"*

Comment: I was referring to the first line of your first code snippet. There is a sequence point just before the call to `container->insert()`, another just after returning and having made a local copy of the return value, and then another after the assignment (overwrite) of `it`. I was arguing that at any of these three sequence points, both `it` and its enclosing `insert_iterator` would be considered both valid or both invalid. I was saying that while this behavior is a useful aspect of an `insert_iterator`, I don't think it is a counterexample to the if-and-only-if claim.